# Optimization in fetching data form Magento Database

Tags: magento-1.7, database, mysql, optimization

I have stuck at one thing. we need to fetch data data form Magento and generate the FEED.

The Problem is that we have around 40,000 products around 715 attributes and around 950 attribute set. one more the I need all filterable attributes in this collection.

When i try to call the Product collection as per default Magento Standard then It will take too much time on server as well as data.

How to optimize the query....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it like this (below) you should not eat all the resources and then fall over. It will still take a fairly long time due to the size of the dataset but will attempt to "Eat the elephant one bite at a time" instead of all at once !!

```
$query = $this->_getReadAdapter()->query($select);
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
 //process row
 add to your feed or whatever... 
}
```

Comment: I will check and update you

Comment: Can you give me query?